# Convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$converges with $$a_n>0 $$  ,show  that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{{a_n}^{1/2}}{n} $$ is convergent.

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks!,prefer simple method!

Comment: Use $ab\le{1\over2}(a^2+b^2)$ and the Comparison Test.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: AM-GM inequality gives: $\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot \sqrt{a_n} \leq \dfrac{1}{2}\left(a_n+ \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

To show a series is convergent, it suffices to show that the sequence of partial sums $\{s_k\}$ converges.  The [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) tells us that monotone increasing sequences that are bounded above converge.  Obviously, $\{s_k\}$ is an increasing sequence, so we just need to show that it is bounded.

To do this, consider the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  In general, this states that
$$\left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_jb_j \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j^2 \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2 \right)$$

At the risk of giving away too much, let the sum on the LHS of the inequality be the $n^\text{th}$ partial sum $s_n$ of the series you're interested in.